# Как можно найти произведение ненулевых элементов в C++?

Tags: c++, массивы, матрицы

[image: На фотографии обведено]

На фотографии ручкой обведено

Вот пример кода :

```
  #include <iostream>
  #include<stdio.h>
  #include <windows.h>
  #define i0 6
 #define j0 5
  using namespace std;
 int main()
{
float a[i0][j0];
float b[j0];
int i, j;
SetConsoleOutputCP(1251);
SetConsoleCP(1251);
cout << "\nВведіть елементи масиву А\n";
 for (i = 0;i<i0;i++)
      for (j = 0;j<j0;j++)
    {
         printf(" Введіть           A[%i,%i]=  \n", i, j);
         cin >> a[i][j];
      }
  for (i = 0;i<i0;i++)
{
      b[i] = 1.0;
    for (j = 0;j<j0;j++)
    {
         if (a[i][j] != 0) b[i]          = b[i] * a[i][j];
       }
    printf("b[%i]=%f\n", i,                 b[i]);
}
return 1;
 }
```

Comment: Я голосую за закрытие этого вопроса, потому что автору лень не только написать задание текстом (желательно на русском), но и даже просто обрезать скриншот.

Answer (score 1):

Диагонали обходятся одним циклом, не вложенным...

```
double p = 1;
for(int i = 0; i < 6; ++i)
{
    if (a[i][i] != 0) p *= a[i][i];
    if (a[i][5-i] != 0) p *= a[i][5-i];
}
```

Comment: это мне надо вставить в свой код , или вместо своего кода ?

Comment: Правильно , да ?

Comment: А может, мне за вас написать все полностью, приехать и сдать? :) Я написал код. Когда вы разберетесь, как он работает, и, например, как нужно его исправить для матрицы 7x7 (а надо не только заменить некоторые цифры), вы поймете, как и куда его встраивать. Если вы рассчитываете просто взять что-то и без понимания, как это работает, воткнуть к себе — рискуете оказаться в положении водителя тяжелого грузовика, который должен крутить педали, чтоб ехать :)